# How to calculate handling fee based on currency and attribute value of cart items in WooCommerce

Tags: php, woocommerce, fee

I have a code snippet running on a Woocommerce site that calculates and adds a handling fee to the cart total.

There are two parts to the calculation:

1. If the shipping rate is greater than 0, then **add 18% of the shipping rate**;
2. If a product in the cart has a particular attribute, **add a set fee dependent on the currency** of the cart.

The snippet does all of this fine, however it fails if the cart contains a mixture of products.

That is, if one product has the particular attribute, and another product doesn't have this attribute, then the set fee is not added.

I need the set fee to be added if at least one product in the cart has this attribute.  Here is the code:

```
<?php
// Hook to add a handling fee
add_action( 'woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees','handling_fee' );
function handling_fee($cart_object) {
  global $woocommerce;

  $specialfeeattr = 71; // attribute id for the special fee

  $spfee = 0.00; // initialize special fee
  $percentage = 0.18; // percentage to add to shipping total

  $orderFeeUSD = 3.20; //fee per transaction USD
  $orderFeeCAD = 4.00; //fee per transaction CAD
  $orderFeeEUR = 2.62; //fee per transaction EUR
  $orderFeeGBP = 2.26; //fee per transaction GBP

  $currentCurrency = get_woocommerce_currency();

  if ( is_admin() && ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) )
      return;

      foreach ( $cart_object->cart_contents as $key => $value ) {

          $proid = $value['product_id']; //get the product id from cart

          $product = wc_get_product( $proid );
      $attr =  $product->get_attributes();

          //check if attributes array has fulfillment attribute included
          if (array_key_exists ('pa_fulfillment', $attr )) {
              $attrFulfillment = $attr['pa_fulfillment'];
          }
          if (isset($attrFulfillment)) {
              $attrFulfillmentOptions = $attrFulfillment['options'];
          }

    if ($woocommerce->cart->shipping_total > 0) {
            $spfee = (($woocommerce->cart->shipping_total) * $percentage);
    }
          //only check if fullfillment option is set to warehouse if fulfillment is not null
          if (isset($attrFulfillmentOptions)) {
              //if the product in cart contains attr id 71
              if (in_array($specialfeeattr, $attrFulfillmentOptions )) {
          if($currentCurrency == 'USD'){
           $spfee += $orderFeeUSD;
         } elseif($currentCurrency == 'CAD') {
           $spfee += $orderFeeCAD;
         } elseif($currentCurrency == 'EUR') {
           $spfee += $orderFeeEUR;
         } elseif($currentCurrency == 'GBP') {
           $spfee += $orderFeeGBP;
                  }
              }
          }
      }

          $woocommerce->cart->add_fee( 'Handling', $spfee, true, 'standard' );
      }

?>
```

Thank you very much for any advice on how to fix this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are initializing the `$spfee` variable with these lines on each iteration:

```
if ( $woocommerce->cart->shipping_total > 0 ) {
    $spfee = $woocommerce->cart->shipping_total * $percentage;
}
```

In this way you only get the sum of the percentage on the shipping *(if this is greater than zero)* and the fee on the last iterated cart item.

Then try to insert the previous lines of code before the start of the loop.

> If you want to apply the standard tax rate, assign a blank value to the fourth parameter of the `add_fee` method, as reported in the [documentation](https://woocommerce.github.io/code-reference/files/woocommerce-includes-class-wc-cart.html#source-view.1909).

Also there are other optimizations to the code, try this:

```
// Hook to add a handling fee
add_action( 'woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees','handling_fee' );
function handling_fee( $cart_object ) {

    if ( is_admin() && ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) ) {
        return;
    }

    global $woocommerce;

    $specialfeeattr  = 71; // attribute id for the special fee

    $spfee           = 0.00; // initialize special fee
    $percentage      = 0.18; // percentage to add to shipping total

    $orderFeeUSD     = 3.20; //fee per transaction USD
    $orderFeeCAD     = 4.00; //fee per transaction CAD
    $orderFeeEUR     = 2.62; //fee per transaction EUR
    $orderFeeGBP     = 2.26; //fee per transaction GBP

    $currentCurrency = get_woocommerce_currency();

    if ( $woocommerce->cart->shipping_total > 0 ) {
        $spfee = $woocommerce->cart->shipping_total * $percentage;
    }

    foreach ( $cart_object->cart_contents as $key => $value ) {

        $proid   = $value['product_id']; //get the product id from cart

        $product = wc_get_product( $proid );
        $attr    = $product->get_attributes();

        //check if attributes array has fulfillment attribute included
        if ( array_key_exists ( 'pa_fulfillment', $attr ) ) {
            $attrFulfillment = $attr['pa_fulfillment'];
        }
        if ( isset($attrFulfillment) ) {
            $attrFulfillmentOptions = $attrFulfillment['options'];
        }

        // only check if fullfillment option is set to warehouse if fulfillment is not null
        if ( isset($attrFulfillmentOptions) ) {
            // if the product in cart contains attr id 71
            if ( in_array( $specialfeeattr, $attrFulfillmentOptions ) ) {
                switch ( $currentCurrency ) {
                    case 'USD':
                        $spfee += $orderFeeUSD;
                        break;
                    case 'CAD':
                        $spfee += $orderFeeCAD;
                        break;
                    case 'EUR':
                        $spfee += $orderFeeEUR;
                        break;
                    case 'GBP':
                        $spfee += $orderFeeGBP;
                        break;
                }
            }
        }

    }

    $woocommerce->cart->add_fee( 'Handling', $spfee, true, 'standard' );
    
}
```

*The code should work. Add it to your active theme's functions.php.*

Comment: This indeed fixed my issue @vincenzo.  I am grateful for your help!